# Extract second level object from JSON while preserving first level key in return value

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I'm trying to pull a value out of nested JSON inside a column. I get the return value, but I am unable to also pull the first JSON key that the value binds to.

Query only pulls 1 row.

Example json:

```json
{
    "key1": {
        "data1": "data1 object",
        "data2": "data2 object"
    },
    "key2": {
        "data1": "data1 object",
        "data2": "data2 object"
    }
}
```

where key `key` values are dynamic and key `data` values are static.

Expected result:

```json
{
    "key1": {
        "data1": "data1 object"
    },
    "key2": {
        "data1": "data1 object"
    }
}
```

or

```json
{
    "key1": "data1 object",
    "key2": "data1 object"
}
```

Not perfectly working query:

```sql
SELECT
    json->>"$.*.data1" AS data
FROM table
WHERE id=1;
```

output:

```json
[
    "data1 object",
    "data1 object"
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT test.id, JSON_OBJECTAGG(jsonkeys.onekey, jsonvalues.onevalue) output
FROM test
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(JSON_KEYS(test.jsondata),
                      '$[*]' COLUMNS (onekey VARCHAR(255) PATH '$')) jsonkeys
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(JSON_EXTRACT(test.jsondata, CONCAT('$.', jsonkeys.onekey)),
                      '$.data1' COLUMNS (onevalue VARCHAR(255) PATH '$'))jsonvalues
GROUP BY test.id
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/uNpzif3g

Comment: Works for data being a string. For other types the part `VARCHAR(255)` in `(onevalue VARCHAR(255) PATH '$')` needs to be changed.

Comment: @Flewz Of course. I create a query according to your sample data. From the other side VARCHAR is the most common datatype, it can receive any data type from JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to resolve it with using `JSON_KEYS()`, effectively returning a map.
I have checked and tested if indexes always correlate and they do.

Updated query:

```sql
SELECT
    JSON_KEYS(json) AS map,
    json->>"$.*.data1" AS data
FROM table
WHERE id=1;
```

Result:

| map | data |
| --- | --- |
| ["key1", "key2"] | ["data1 object", "data1 object"] |